# set GitKraken as git mergetool

Tags: git, gitkraken, mergetool

Is it possible to set GitKraken as the default git mergetool?  Something like this code for p4merge, but for GitKraken?

`git config --global merge.tool p4merge`

`git config --global mergetool.p4merge.path "/Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/MacOS/p4merge"`

Handling merge conflicts in GitKraken is easiest, but I am not sure if it can be opened from the command line in the same way as other mergetools.

Comment: The closest I came was to add an alias to open GitKraken in my `.zshrc` as `alias kraken="(cd  ~/../../Applications/GitKraken.app/Contents/MacOS && GitKraken)" ` then navigate to the app and resolve the merge conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You usually find the opposite: using an external tool as merge *from* GitKraken.
*Not* using GitKraken itself.

That is what the [GitKraken documentation](https://support.gitkraken.com/working-with-repositories/branching-and-merging/#external-merge-tools) illustrates:

> Configure GitKraken Client to launch your tool of choice
>
> [image: https://support.gitkraken.com/img/documentation/repositories/local_repository/configureExternalTool.png]

Comment: Yes, thanks!  I found this feature and wondered if this was a hold over from a time when GitKraken did not have its own, good merge conflict resolution feature.  They do have one now.  It's hard for me to picture why it would not be possible to use GitKraken as a mergetool.